# How to retain edit history in netbeans ide even after system shut down on windows?

Tags: windows, netbeans

After I make edits to files using netbeans, I could undo my changes using CTRL+Z and redo using CTRL+Y. But after I shutdown the system(Windows 7) and start again, files that were open are still open but I can no longer use CTRL+Z to undo my changes nor CTRL+Y to redo.

So my question is,

**Is there a way to make CTRL+Z and CTRL+Y to work in netbeans IDE even after Windows restart.**

I am not sure if this is a windows related question or netbeans related question. So i have tagged both.

Do not want to use hibernate/sleep modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not currently exist in Netbeans IDE. It does seem like a very nice feature to have, so I have submitted a feature request https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=261533

However, there is history tab in the editor window that lets you revert to any previously saved version of the file. Or you can always initialize a revision control system (Mercurial, Git, or Subversion) and then create your own save points by making frequent commits.